# Convert SQL string field into unix timestamp

Tags: mysql, sql, unix

I have a field, 'mydate' in my database which displays the date as a string like this

```
'8/1/2015 12:35:22 PM'
```

I am trying to convert this into a unix timestamp i have tried

```
cast(UNIX_TIMESTAMP('mydate',"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSS")) AS new_date
```

This has resulted in the query not completing completely. How can i convert this 'mydate' field into a unix timestamp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
UNIX_TIMESTAMP(STR_TO_DATE(mydate, '%M %e %Y %h:%i%p'))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply check in mysql string format -

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE('8/1/2015 11:35:22 PM','%d/%m/%Y %h:%i:%s %p');
```